# Fetch API giving 404 not found error In Netlify

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, netlify

This is my test site on which I am working.

https://keen-archimedes-cc5aba.netlify.app/

I am using fetch for post API

```
fetch('/.netlify/functions/get-protected-content', {
        method: 'POST',
         body: JSON.stringify({ type }),
       })
```

It's giving 404 error.

[image]

This is my folder directory

[image]

My Publish directory is "_book" I am calling above API from index.html inside "_book" folder.

It gives not found error.

When I am moving "functions" folder inside "_book" it's also not working.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by using:

```
fetch('./.netlify/functions/get-protected-content/get-protected-content.js', {
        method: 'POST',
         body: JSON.stringify({ type }),
       })
```

My file hierarchy is:

/functions/get-protected-content/get-protected-content.js

I run the app with `netlify dev`

I have the following in my `/netlify.toml` config file in the root of the app:

```
[functions]
  directory = "functions"

[build]
    functions = "functions"
    publish = "dist/"
```